# Protractor: waiting for an element to become visible

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I have a directive in which I show a pop-up after 10 seconds (using setTimeout), and would like to test that it appears correctly.  But I don't want to have the test wait an actual 10 seconds.  How can I fake the clock moving forward?

I tried using jasmine's `Clock.tick()` like this:

```
jasmine.Clock.useMock();
expect(modal.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
jasmine.Clock.tick(10001);
expect(modal.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

But that doesn't work.  I think I'm missing something.

Comment: The code of your test is executed by Node.js. The JavaScript code waiting for 10 seconds to show the modal is executed by the browser.

Comment: Oh man, I still have a lot to learn before I even begin to understand this stuff.... Thanks!